# Change the different background color of p tags

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="r_1" class="white"></div>
<div id="r_2" class="black"></div>
<div id="r_3" class="blue"></div>
<div id="r_4" class="red"></div>
<div id="r_5" class="green"></div>
<div id="r_6" class="white"></div>

<p id="p_r_1"> some...</p>
<p id="p_r_2"> some...</p>
<p id="p_r_3"> some...</p>
<p id="p_r_4"> some...</p>
<p id="p_r_5"> some...</p>
<p id="p_r_6"> some...</p>
```

On each div click, I need to change the different background color of `p` tags respectively.
Sometimes the count of number of `div` & `p` tags may vary.

Comment: Which background color do you want to apply? Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: ironically a down voted a demoted question has got very good answers ....@jurgenstillaert and @undefined have shown us what help and willingness are. Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

```
var $div = $('div'), $p = $('p');    
// var $div = $('div[id^="r_"]'), $p = $('p[id^="p_r"]');

$div.on('click', function(){
   var ind = $div.index(this);
   $p.eq(ind).addClass(this.className);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WdJZ6/

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divColurs div").click(function(){

       $("#p_" + $(this).attr("id")).css("background-color",$(this).attr("class"));        
   });
});​
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GrgKd/

Answer (score 0):

This would be the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/CdFQJ/

```
$('div[id^="r_"]').click(function() {
    $("#p_" + $(this).attr("id")).css("background-color", $(this).attr("class"));
});
```